# ¿Como ubico un boton en la esquina superior derecha con pantalla completa en tkinter sin saber cual es la resolucion de el monitor?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

estoy intentando posicionar un boton en la esquina superior derecha, pero hay un solo problema, yo no puedo saber la esquina superior derecha porque la aplicacion es a pantalla completa, no puse una linea de codigo como esta

```
root.geometry("1024x768")
```

Yo, puse este codigo que genera que la ventana se ponga a pantalla completa,no que se maximize, que se ponga a pantalla completa, ya que se pone a pantalla completa, no se la resolucion de la pantalla y no puedo saber las coordenadas de la esquina superior derecha, no la esquina superior izquierda, ya que las coordenadas son x=0 y=0,yo quiero la esquina superior derecha

```
root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
```

Ayudenme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiento que el tamaño de la ventana es igual al de la pantalla, podemos usar
el método `winfo_screenwidth` para obtener el largo de esta.

En el método place vamos a usar un argumento llamado anchor, que nos dice que parte del botón vamos a ubicar en esas coordenadas. En este caso conviene ubicar la esquina noreste del widget en dichas coordenadas.

```
import tkinter as tk

v = tk.Tk()
v.attributes("-fullscreen",True)

button = tk.Button(v, text="hola mundo")
button.place(x=v.winfo_screenwidth(), y=0, anchor="ne")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dante.

Comment: De nada fourseven c:

Comment: tengo otra pregunta, si quiero ponerla en la esquina inferior derecha como hago?

Comment: Hola, perdon por la respuesta tarde. Puedes obtener el alto de la pantalla con winfo_screenwidth. Para entender como funciona el argumento anchor puedes leer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm. Con estas dos cosas deberías de poderlo resolver por ti mismo c:

Comment: Me corrigo, puedes obtener el alto de la pantalla con winfo_screenheight

Comment: gracias ;) eres un genio

Comment: De nada fourseven ;)